# How do I code 'for in for loop' in jinja2?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am making web service with flask, and having trouble with jinja2 'for loop in for loop'. I made 'for loop in for loop' but it is not returning right. for example. (I made it simple because original code is more complex)

```
numbers1 = {{"value":1},{"value":2},{"value":3}}
numbers2 = {{"value":1},{"value":2},{"value":3}}

    {% for num1 in numbers1 %}
            {{num1.value}}
            {% for num2 in numbers2 %}
                {% if num2.value == num1.value %}
                    {{num2.value}}
                {% else %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

and the result was look like this

```
11 2 3
```

but I was trying to get result like this

```
11 22 33
```

I tried several different ways, but I could not solve it. Really think you if you could help me. Thanks

Comment: You should try zip function to get the desired result. That way it will be easy.

Comment: Please confirm that `numbers1` and `numbers2` are sets of dictionaries

Comment: sorry~~ num is num1... the point is that second for loop is not working right.

Answer (score 0):

Change num1 to num, and then try if it works!

Comment: opps sorry~ num is num1. I edited. the point is that second for loop is not working as I expected in jinja2

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected with:

```
from jinja2 import Template

tmpl = Template("{% for num1 in numbers1 %}{{num1.value}}{% for num2 in numbers2 %}{% if num2.value == num1.value %}{{num2.value}}{% else %}{% endif %}{% endfor %}{% endfor %}")

print(tmpl.render(
    numbers1 = [{"value":1},{"value":2},{"value":3}],
    numbers2 = [{"value":1},{"value":2},{"value":3}]
))
```

Your issue should be elsewhere.